# HttpURLConnection Locally works fine with all urls but , it doesn't on server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I've been trying to get HTTP status code for some Urls it works fine with me on local but it doesn't on the server

```
try {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            String url = "https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/industrial_strength/archive/2016/02/17/trends-in-building-automation-energy-efficiency?HQS=hpa-mhrs-ssc-sensingoverview-asset-blog-null-wwe&DCM=yes";
            URL u;
            u = new URL(url);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setUseCaches(false);
            con.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println("Done in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

this Url on local will get 200 
but on server it will get nothing 
[image]

Comment: Is the internet accessible from EC2 ?

Comment: yes the internet is accessible